# General probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

What's the correct way to solve following question:
Dima has to pick 4 digit password (1-9 inclusive). Every digit is picked randomly.
What's the probability of picking at least 1 even digit?
Thank you

Comment: How many possible 4 digits passwords are there? How many of these have only odd digits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with complementary counting. The probability of picking at least 1 even digit complements the probability of picking all odd digits, which is $\left (\frac{5}{9}\right)^4 = \frac{625}{6561}$, so the answer is $$1 - \frac{625}{6561} = \boxed{\frac{5936}{6561}}$$

Comment: Thank you very much!